# How to create an API specific environment for Android SDK/Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying (unsuccessfully, and getting extremely frustrated), to create an API specific environment for Eclipse.

I want to create an environment that supports API 17 ONLY.  No other APIs installed.  I successfully did this a couple months ago, but apparently, some update now (after 5.0 Lollipop was released), any attempt to install ANYTHING via the SDK manager installs API 21.  I don't want it - it isn't checked, but it constantly installs.

And, in the process, screws up my environment.  If I attempt to remove it, I get errors:

```
Parsing Data for android-21 failed
    Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I have NO idea where the major.minor version referenced is - it doesn't show up in the project properties at all.

If I leave API 21 installed (as it keeps insisting to do), then I can't access my layout properly, i.e. /res/layout/activity_??_settings.xml.  The graphical layout shows nothing, there is nothing in the palette, and I get the messages:

```
The rendering target (Android 5.0) is still loading.
The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.
```

These two messages NEVER go away.  I've tried cleaning the project (I only have one), repeatedly, and nothing seems to work.

HELP!  What do I do to get an API 17 only environment?  I need to get something set up for a specific project for a class, that follows my textbook, but simply can't get around these issues.

Comment: "create an API specific environment for Eclipse" -- Eclipse is no longer supported, and the ADT plugin has issues. New Android developers should consider another IDE, such as Android Studio. "These two messages NEVER go away" -- change the API level that the preview uses, in the drop-down in the toolbar immediately above the preview window.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I may have found the solution.

I understand the answer that Eclipse is no longer supported - but that isn't an answer to my specific issue.  I *must* follow a textbook, and it's examples, and, and, and.  That doesn't give me any flexibility.  Sorry - have had this class "placed" on me last minute, and I haven't used Eclipse/Android for quite a while.  I don't have time to rewrite the textbook to accommodate the new stuff (which needs to be done, but I've got 5 days left, and I can't rewrite the textbook to change all references to Eclipse menu/rtclick options to whatever else in 5 days, much less avoid potential copyright issues).

My solution (on an OSX 10.10.1 platform, which seems to work so far):

```
Use Eclipse Juno M20130204-1200
First thing - make sure the latest Android SDK Manager is installed, 24.0.2 - and install it ONLY (or if anything else is installed, remove all of it, then install the SDK Manager 24.0.2) 
Second - install the specific API desired.  What I have installed for API 17:

Tools
    Android SDK Tools             24.0.2
    Android SDK Platform-tools    21
    Android SDK Build-tools       17
Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
    SDK Platform               17 3
    Samples for SDK            17 1
    ARM EABI V7a System Image  17 2
    Google APIs                17 3
    Sources for Android SDK    17 1
Android 2.2 (API 8)
    SDK Platform                8 3
Extras
    Android Support Library       21.0.3
```

The Samples and Google APIs probably aren't necessary for the class, and I may remove them.

After that's done, when on the layout view screen in Eclipse, click the button "Android version to use when rendering layouts in Eclipse" to the correct API (in my case - 17).  This then seems to work.  For whatever reason, this always defaults to the latest API - installed or not.

I'll proceed, hoping these items will at least get me through the section of the class dealing with Android.